# Usar Object ou Iframe para importar outros sites para meu site

Tags: html, iframe

Estava precisando importar várias páginas aleatórias de outros sites para meu site. Wikipédia, por exemplo. Vi que posso utilizar ou Iframe (esse deu certo) ou Object (não mostra o conteúdo).

Depois, gostaria de adicionar outra formatação específica para essas páginas que estou importando, mas não consegui. Isso é possível?

O projeto é: importar a URL das Leis, por exemplo a Constituição e aplicar uma nova formação para melhor leitura ou mesmo anotação sobre os artigos de lei. Estava na esperança de um `<iframe>` ou `<object>` resolver, o que não aconteceu.

Comment: Você quer estilizar o conteúdo dos iframes?

Comment: o que seria o tal "Object" e o que quer dizer com "adicionar outra formatação específica para essas páginas que estou importando" ?

Comment: Não é possível manipular o conteúdo de um iFrame se o mesmo não estiver no mesmo domínio do seu Site. o que você pode fazer, é enviar uma requisição AJAX para o seu site, o seu server baixa o HTML desejado e devolve o trecho do HTML desejado.

Comment: @TobyMosque Como fazer isso? Tem algum exemplo. Não conheço nada de Ajax. E só para deixar claro, o projeto é: Importar a url das Leis, por exemplo a Constituilção e aplicar uma nova formação para melhor leitura ou mesmo anotação sobre os artigos de lei.

Comment: Qual a tecnologia Server-Side? PHP, ASP.NET, Java, NodeJS, Ruby, etc? Ou está usando um gerenciador de conteúdo tipo o WordPress?

Comment: @TobyMosque Não pensei nisso ainda. Estava na esperança de um <iframe> ou <object> resolver, o que não aconteceu. Mas Wordpress não seria problema.

Comment: Você pode adicionar um exemplo do link ou conteúdo, talvez o site aceite CORS ou disponibilize um Feed para o material que deseja.

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 5):

infelizmente você não vai conseguir modificar o estilo do conteudo de um iFrame que aponta para outro dominio, uma vez que você não terá acesso ao `document` do mesmo.

caso a pagina de destino permita `CORS`, você pode fazer uma requisição `AJAX` e colar o HTML direto em algum elemento, por exemplo uma `<div>`.

Caso a pagina de destino não aceite CORS, você pode usar um proxy ou escrever o seu proprio, um exemplo de proxy para CORS é o [`crossorigin`](http://crossorigin.me), caso prefira escrever o seu proprio proxy, basicamente faça uma requisição Web no seu servidor e retorne o HTML desta pagina usando o seu dominio.

Segue um exemplo de como usar um `proxy` para burlar o `CORS` e jogar o conteudo dentro de um iFrame...

```js
var CORSFrame = function (iFrame) {
  var self = this;
  this.onload = null;
  this.iFrame = iFrame;

  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("GET", self.corsProxy + self.iFrame.dataset.src, false);
  httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
        var content = template.content.getElementById("content");
        var blob = new Blob(['<meta charset="utf-8">' + content.outerHTML], { 
          type: 'text/html;' 
        });
        
        var bUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        self.iFrame.src = bUrl;
      }
    }
  });
  httpRequest.send();
}
CORSFrame.prototype.corsProxy = "http://crossorigin.me/";

var iFrames = document.querySelectorAll("iframe[data-src]");
[].forEach.call(iFrames, function (iFrame, indice) {  
  var corsFrame = new CORSFrame(iFrame);
  iFrame.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    var doc = iFrame.contentWindow.document;    
    doc.body.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    doc.body.style.color = "white";
  })
});
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

html, body, iframe {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px none transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="wikipedia" data-src="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituição">

</iframe>
```

Devido a uma limitação do StackOverFlow, o exemplo acima não vai funcionar, mas você pode conferir ele no seguinte [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xjcf60t/1/)

Lembrando que é bem mais simples, jogar o conteudo HTML direto em uma `<div>`.

```js
var CORSFrame = function (element) {
  var self = this;
  this.onload = null;
  this.element = element;

  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("GET", self.corsProxy + self.element.dataset.src, false);
  httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
        var template = document.createElement("template");
        template.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
        var content = template.content.getElementById("content");
        self.element.innerHTML = content.outerHTML;
      }
    }
  });
  httpRequest.send();
}
CORSFrame.prototype.corsProxy = "http://crossorigin.me/";

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]");
[].forEach.call(elements, function (element, indice) {  
  var corsFrame = new CORSFrame(element);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

[data-src] {
  overflow: auto;
}

html, body, [data-src] {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px none transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wikipedia {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wikipedia" data-src="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituição">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode carregar os conteúdos no iFrame:

```
<iframe id="estilizado" src="externo.html"></iframe>
```

E em seguida acessar seus elementos via `jQuery` ou `Javascript`:

```
var seuIFrame = (document.getElementById("estilizado").contentWindow || document.getElementById("estilizado").contentDocument);

if (seuIFrame.document) {
    seuIFrame = seuIFrame.document;
}

seuIFrame.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
```

fonte:[Como mudar o CSS de um iframe a partir de uma página "pai"](http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/423876-como-mudar-o-css-de-um-iframe-a-partir-de-uma-pagina-pai/).

**Via jQuery**:
[Como acessar um iframe e seus elementos via jQuery?](http://www.diogosouza.com.br/2011/10/como-acessar-um-iframe-e-seus-elementos.html)

---

Em todo caso, ainda existem meios de buscar só o conteúdo desses sites, através do `PHP`, `Ruby` e até `jQuery` sei que é possível. Isso permitiria a você estilizar o conteúdo dos mesmos e inseri-los diretamente no seu site.

Talvez isso seja útil:

- [The DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [Getting data from an external webpage - stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004878/getting-data-from-an-external-webpage)
- [Searching & Extracting Specific text in external webpage via PHP? - stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230422/searching-extracting-specific-text-in-external-webpage-via-php)
- [PHP: file_get_contents - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [Ruby: retrieve contents of URL as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193538/ruby-retrieve-contents-of-url-as-string)
- [How to get data from an external URL in jQuery? - stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629254/how-to-get-data-from-an-external-url-in-jquery)